# Underline element and increase distance between them on navbar with sliding underline

Tags: html, css

I have a menu with an sliding underline: http://z-testing.000webhostapp.com/navbar-underline/

The problem I have is the line underlines the block completely, not just the word:
[image]

What I want is to underline just the word and have the possibility to increase the distance between elements:
[image]

And **still keep the sliding transition between them:**
[image]

This is the fiddle where I got the code:
https://jsfiddle.net/5cLf6gck/

This is my CSS:

```
.navbar-nav li {
  font-family: sans-serif;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: gray;
  position: relative;
  margin: 10px 0px;
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 0px 25px 3px;
}

.navbar-nav li::after {
  content: "";
  background: $black-main;
  height: 2px;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0px;
  transition: .16s all 0.025s;
}

.navbar-nav  li::after {
  left: 100%;
  right: 0;
}

.navbar-nav li:hover ~ li::after {
  left: 0;
  right: 100%;
}

.navbar-nav  li:hover::after {
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
}

.navbar-nav  li.active::after {
  content: "";
  background: $black-main;
  height: 2px;
  position: absolute;
  bottom:0px;
  transition: .16s all 0.025s;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
}
```

Comment: you'll have to use some javascript to do that, you can't rely on just css or you won't be able to underline only text

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to update size and position of your underlining element with javascript

```js
const navBar = document.getElementById("nav");
const navCursor = navBar.querySelector('.cursor');
const navItems = navBar.querySelectorAll('a');

function handleMouseEnterNavItem(event) {
  // executed when mouse enter a navigation item
  // update cursor to match position and size of target
  const { offsetLeft, clientWidth } = event.target;
  navCursor.style.left = offsetLeft + 'px';
  navCursor.style.width = clientWidth + 'px';
}

navItems.forEach((navItem) => {
  navItem.addEventListener('mouseenter', handleMouseEnterNavItem);
});
```

```css
nav {
  position: relative;
}

nav a {
  font-family: sans-serif;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: gray;
  margin: 22px 10px 10px;
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 0; /* note: padding will be underlined */
}

nav .cursor {
  background: blue;
  height: 1px;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  z-index: 10;
  transition: .16s all 0.025s;
}
```

```html
<nav id="nav">
  <a href="#">News</a>
  <a href="#">Activities</a>
  <a href="#">Search</a>
  <a href="#">Time</a>
  <div class="cursor"></div>
</nav>
```

Comment: thanks, looks good! can you help me to make it work when the user resizes the screen?

Comment: as far as I know what you are trying to do, I don't think you need to react to resize because element are measured when mouse enter them

Comment: @Apolo I have something like this but with waaaaaay more jQuery. Was looking to update and this is perfect. Do you think it'd work if one of the items had a class on `active` and the linked moved from there?

Comment: @user1406440 it would work, but it would not go back to the active element when you stop hovering any menu item. You would need to add a mouseleave listener on menu items, check if the mouse is not entering another menu item (use `leaveEvent.relatedTarget`), and if so you can  reset left/width of the cursor to be under the active element

Comment: @Apolo I had something similar working (here: https://codepen.io/moy/pen/pZdjMX) but all with jQuery. Might look into seeing if any of it can be refactored!

Answer (score 0):

Try this one

```css
nav a {
  font-family: sans-serif;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: gray;
  position: relative;
  margin: 10px 0;
  display: inline-block;
  padding-bottom:5px;
  margin: 12px 10px;
}

nav a::after {
  content: "";
  background: blue;
  height: 2px;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;

}

nav a::after {
  left: 100%;
  right: 0;
}

nav a:hover ~ a::after {
  left: 0;
  right: 100%;
}

nav a:hover::after {
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
}
```

```html
<nav>
    <a href="#">News</a><a href="#">Activities</a><a href="#">Search</a><a href="#">Time</a>
</nav>
```

Comment: Thanks but it cuts the underline when you hover between words, see my third image for reference

Comment: removed the transition, check now

Comment: no, it should do the opposite, mantain the transition between words, that's the problem I have :)